# HTML5: Make an entire table row clickable without javascript

Tags: html

I would like to have an entire table row clickable, without using javascript. The Internets tell me this isn't possible with HTML4, but I'm using HTML5, so I'm hopeful.

However, the obvious doesn't work:

```
<table>    
    <a href="foo">
        <tr>
            <td>…</td>
            <td>…</td>
        </tr>
    </a>
</table>
```

Firebug reveals that Firefox pulls the `<tr/>` element out of the `<a/>` wrapper when computing the element tree, and puts an empty `<a/>` before the `<table/>` like this:

```
<a href="foo"> </a>
<table>
    …
</table>
```

This looks to me like what I'm trying is either not allowed by the standard, or there's a bug in Firefox (and Chromium, which showed the same behaviour). I'm guessing the former, and indeed, the HTML5 specification tells us that `<td/>` can't be used within an `<a/>` element, but only within other table-elements: [The tr element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element).

Any other hints on how I could achieve clickable table rows using HTML5?

Comment: Why is it that you would like to avoid JavaScript?

Comment: Can you not repeat the same link in every column for the row?

Comment: _“The Internets tell me this isn't possible with HTML4, but I'm using HTML5”_ – then the internets have been lying to you, or you misunderstood them. `table` can not have `a` as a child element, and neither can `a` be the parent of a `tr`.

Comment: Absolutely positioning <a> element over the table row and giving it the same width and height

Comment: @CBroe: It's you who's misunderstanding. The complete sentence is, "The Internets tell me this isn't possible with HTML4, but I'm using HTML5, **so I'm hopeful**" (emphasis mine). In other words, the OP has read that this is not possible in HTML4, but has not determined whether the same is true of HTML5.

Comment: @ruakh OK, good point. But hasn’t changed in HTML5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this hasn’t changed in HTML5, so we’re still left with the mentioned workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the clickable row span the number of columns you need and put the content I that one row

```
<table>    
        <tr>
            <td>col 1</td>
            <td>col 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td colspan="2">
                <a href="foo">
                   Clickable stuff.  If you need table columns here, you can nest a second table here
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```